# Bestpractice fetching orders together with orderlines

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture

I would like to improve the way I get order and line items from my order database.

I am using "using System.Data.SqlClient;"

I'm doing a select on the order table with a join over to the line item table.

A select may return something like this:

```
OrderId ProductName Price   OrderTotal
------------------------------------------
00  Blue Jeans  200,-   500,-
------------------------------------------
00  Red Shirt   100,-   500,-
------------------------------------------
00  Green Shirt 100,-   500,-
------------------------------------------
00  Black Shirt 100,-   500,-
------------------------------------------
01  Green Shirt 100,-   300,-
------------------------------------------
01  Black shoes 200,-   300,-
------------------------------------------
02  Black Shirt 150,-   150,-
------------------------------------------
```

Like you can see the order information (orderId and OrderTotal) comes out multiple times but I only need to read this once. Orderline information (Productname and

Price) is unique and I need each line.

When I create a list of orders, I do something like this:

```
var processedOrderId = string.Empty();
var orderList = List<Order>();

while (reader.Read())
{
    if (processedOrderId != reader["orderID"].ToString())
    {
        var order = new Order
        {

            OrderId = reader["orderID"] as string,
            OrderTotal = reader["orderTotal"] as string
        };

        order.OrderLines = new List<OrderLine>();
        orderList.Add(order);
    }

    var orderLine = new OrderLine
    {
        Name = reader["ProductName"] as string,
        Price = reader["price"] as string
    };

    orderList[orderList.Count - 1].OrderLines.Add(orderLine);

    processedOrderId = reader["orderID"].ToString();
}
```

It quickly becomes messy when there are added several other properties to order and orderline and ifs/elses to the method.

I have considered doing this:

```
var processedOrderId = string.Empty();
var orderList = List<Order>();

while (reader.Read())
{
  if (processedOrderId != reader["orderID"].ToString())
    {
        var order = GetOrder(reader);
        order.OrderLines = new List<OrderLine>();
        orderList.Add(order);
    }

    var orderLine = GetOrderline(reader);

    orderList[orderList.Count - 1].OrderLines.Add(orderLine);

    processedOrderId = reader["orderID"].ToString();
}
```

I would like to avoid too many calls to the database but have also considered the following:

```
var orderList = List<Order>();

while (reader.Read())
{
    var order = GetOrder(reader);

    order.OrderLines = GetOrderlinesForOrder(order.OrderId); // This calls a method that opens a new connection and read from the database etc

    orderList[orderList.Count - 1].OrderLines.Add(orderLine);

}
```

Can this be done differently? What is best practice here?

Comment: Can you use Entity Framework?

Comment: Hi @Win, I am working in MVC but the orders is from an existing database

Comment: Hi @Win, I am using MVC and my own databse for the main project. But the orders are placed in another database that I am allowed to read from but not change/modulate. Can I still us EF and do something like this: http://odetodata.com/2014/12/using-entity-framework-code-first-with-an-existing-database-part-1/

Comment: @Win I ended up using MVC. Entity Framework Code First to an Existing Database: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should in general have 2 separate db calls: one for Order details and one to get OrderLines for given Order. not only because of this particular issue but because you in general need both: for showing list of orders, for example, you dont need lines.

now, thats where tests and the way your app is being used comes into play. if you mostly show lists of orders and aggregate amount on Order and rarely orderlines thes its pretty ok to leave 2 calls. on the other hand, if you, for whatever reason, see its not good enough for you then you can try to optimize two db calls into one. One possible approach is like this:

```
while(reader.Read()) {
//read your order here
}

reader.NexResult();

while(reader.Read()) {
//read your orderlines here
//and assign them to order you have read earlier
}
```

This assumes in your stored procedures that you have 2 SELECTs: one for orders and one for orderlines.

This is a good place to repeat a good thought: Premature optimization is a root of all evil:).

Important note: when you call connection.Open() that most usually doesnt mean new connection is being established. Thats what connection pooler does for you.

Comment: Hi @dee zg This was exactly such input I was looking for - A little code and some thoughts. Thanks - have a great summer :)

Comment: @LasseBj glad you find it useful;)